# Почему margin-left:auto; прижал элемент влево, но сам прижался вправо?

Tags: css, margin

Я хотел оттолкнуть первый элемент влево, прописав второму margin-left:auto; но второй элемент тоже оттолкнутся и прижался вправо.Почему второй элемент прижался вправо? В чем моя ошибка? Огромное спасибо за помощь!

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content:center;
}

.child-1{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

}

.child-2{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы указываете здесь отступ auto, браузер пытается сделать его максимально возможным. Здесь это такой, что в результате два элемента окажутся по бокам. Они как бы и остались вместе по центру (указан `justify-content:center`), но отступ между ними максимальный, то есть во всю ширину контейнера.

Нужно смотреть на макет: что именно нужно получить и как это должно работать вместе. Вот что придумал сделать, чтобы получилось, как вы хотите (один элемент по центру, один с краю):

1. Вариант на гридах. Сделать три колонки, правая пустая.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.child-1{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child-2{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

2. Вариант с флексами, здесь отступ между элементами высчитывается (но есть зависимость от размеров элементов).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  column-gap: calc(50% - 1.5 * 100px);
}

.child-1{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child-2{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

3. Вариант с флексами. Делаем третий несуществующий элемент в разметке и задаем равномерное расстояние между всеми.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: space-between;;
  
}

.child-1{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child-2{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child-3{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
  <div class="child-3"></div>
</div>
```

4. Центральный элемент можно сделать через флексы, а элемент слева прижать через абсолютное позиционирование.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.child-1{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.child-2{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ и за примеры решения!